# Error with cmake when trying to build wt?

Tags: cmake

Check for working C compiler: cl

Check for working C compiler: cl -- broken

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake 2.6/share/cmake-2.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:32

(MESSAGE):The C compiler "cl" is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: C:/Users/Gilg/Documents/Projects/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:\PROGRA~1\MI30EB~1\Common7\IDE\devenv.com
  CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.sln /build Debug /project cmTryCompileExec

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 8.0.50727.762.

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005.  All rights reserved.

1>------ Build started: Project: cmTryCompileExec, Configuration: Debug
  Win32 ------

1>Compiling...

1>Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762
  for 80x86

1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

1>cl /Od /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\""
  /D "_MBCS" /FD /RTCs /MDd /Fo"cmTryCompileExec.dir\Debug\"
  /Fd"C:/Users/Gilg/Documents/Projects/builds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec.pdb"
  /W3 /c /Zi /TC /Zm1000

1> .\testCCompiler.c

1>testCCompiler.c

**1>.\testCCompiler.c : fatal error C1033: cannot open program database**

1>Build log was saved at
  "file://c:\Users\Gilg\Documents\Projects\builds\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec.dir\Debug\BuildLog.htm"

1>cmTryCompileExec - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

I have added the paths, $(SystemRoot), $(SystemRoot)\System32,$(SystemRoot)\System32\wbem to the vc++ directories in MCVS 2005 and yet I still get this problem. Im not sure what else to do. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What version of Windows are you compiling on? If on Windows 7 with MCVS 2005 try running it with vista compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is wrong with how you ran cmake. Erase your entire project, restart from scracth by following [the wt on windows installation instructions](http://redmine.emweb.be/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_MS_Windows)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a similar problem recently and it was due to cygwin being in path before the VC200x binary. Solved by placing \cygwin\bin at the very last in C++ Directories->Executables Directories and took it completely out of the system environment path.